# In the ANT build.xml, why can't we use both jar and classpath together in the java task

Tags: java, ant

In the ANT build.xml, why can't we use both jar and classpath together in the Java task?

Comment: Don't understand - do mean jar and classname?  Can you give an example of what you would do, if it was possible?

Comment: @user496949 - Could you please accept if any one of the answer seems to have answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I understood you question wrong you should be able to do that easily. I am assuming you want to include jars in a classpath and a set of jars in another folder.

You can do something like this:-

```
<property name="classpath" value="./WEB-INF/lib"/>
<property name="dependency" value="./libs"/>
<path id = "my-classpath">
        <fileset dir = "${classpath}">
                <include name = "**/**.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir = "${dependency}">
                <include name = "**/**.jar"/>
        </fileset>      
</path>

<javac destdir="${build.dir}">
  <src path="${src.dir}"/>
  <classpath refid="my-classpath"/>
</javac>
```

**EDIT**

As you also mentioned java task. The below example should be what you are looking for I think. Let me know if this is not it.

```
 <path id="project.class.path">  
     <pathelement location="somejar.jar"/>  
     <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>  
     <pathelement path="${additional.dependencies}"/>  
 </path>  
 <java jar="test.jar" classpathref="project.class.path" ... />
```

Comment: Modify the question. I mean java task. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user496949 - sure. See my edits. Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean why the `java` task ignores your classpath settings when you use it with a `jar` attribute. From the [ant `java` docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

> When using the jar attribute, all classpath settings are ignored according to [Sun's specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#-jar).

and from that link:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

So the answer is simply that it's like that because it's following the spec.

If this is an issue for you, you can either add the jar file in question to the classpath and then use the normal `classname` attribute to specify the class to run, or if you're building the jar yourself you can add a `Class-Path` entry to the manifest file when you create it. The [`manifest`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html) and [`manifestclasspath`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) tasks may be helpful there.